# What exactly means left and right side of instance

Tags: java

Assuming following case:

```
Logger logger = new ConsoleLogger();
```

Shouldn't that be

```
ConsoleLogger logger = new ConsoleLogger()
```

Why is the name on the left side different to the name on the right side?

Comment: because they use a more generic type. It's programming against interfaces

Comment: You should learn about Polymorphism in Java. `Logger` is an interface, `ConsoleLogger` is a class that implements that interface.

Comment: @Stultuske this isn't only about Interfaces, but also about Classes.

Comment: @user2342558 programming/coding against interfaces is one of the names given to working this way.

Answer (score 2):

In Java it's called [Polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

```
Logger logger = new ConsoleLogger();
```

`Logger` is the type that `logger` accepts. It may be any object of type `Logger` or a subclass of it. By that reason you see a different type.

In practice, this means that you can define something like this:

```
Animal animals = new Dog(); // Dog extends Animal
Animal animals = new Cat(); // Cat extends Animal
...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Logger logger = new ConsoleLogger();
```

is *probably* a field declaration (it could also be a local variable declaration, if found within the body of a method, but the types suggest it's at the class level).

Here `Logger` is the *type of the variable* `logger`. `new ConsoleLogger()` is the value we initialize `logger` with. `ConsoleLogger` is almost certainly a subclass of `Logger` (or a class implementing `Logger` if that is an interface).

Simply speaking you want the variable to be the most generic type that still has all the required methods. In this case you want the code that *uses* the `logger` variable to not know that it's logging to the console. You just want it to use the methods that the `Logger` class (or interface) provides without any regard what the specific implementation is.